# Anonymous block errors with "ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows"

Tags: oracle, plsql

This is my code:

```
declare

    name1 varchar2(25);

    code number(3):=1;
begin
    while(code<10)
    loop

    select attrname into name1 from catregionmap where attrtype=code;

    dbms_output.put_line('The name for' || name1 || 'ways' );

    code:= code+1;

    end loop;

end;
```

But I get this error:

> "ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows"

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use a Cursor. The main reason why a cursor is used is in order to avoid the problem / issue faced by you. For the code from which you have received the oracle error "Too many" We can simply re write the code by using a simple cursor as given below (You have hard coded the value of attrtype between 1 and 10).

```
DECLARE
    name1                                   VARCHAR2(25);
    code                                    NUMBER(3) := 1;

    CURSOR c1  IS
        SELECT attrname
          FROM catregionmap
         WHERE attrtype <= 10;
BEGIN
    OPEN c1;

    LOOP
        FETCH c1 INTO name1;

        EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('The name for' || name1 || 'ways');
        code    := code + 1;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE c1;
END;
```

Please make a note of yourself that cursors are effectively used when number of records are being fetched from the select query. The code given by my friend XING is also correct as BULK collect is a way of avoiding cursor usage. I would suggest you to read the PLSQL manual better and gain knowledge in cursor and Bulk collect options.

Hope this would help you out. Thanks.!!!

Answer (score 0):

The issue states that your `select` statement is returning more than `1` rows and you are trying to store `many` rows to a `single` variable `name1` . In that case you need a `collection` to store your values.

Use this way:

```
DECLARE
   type name11   is table of catregionmap.attrname%type index by pls_integer;
   name1  name11;
   code    NUMBER (3) := 1;

BEGIN
   WHILE (code < 10)
   LOOP
      SELECT attrname
        BULK COLLECT INTO name1
        FROM catregionmap
       WHERE attrtype = code;

       for rec in 1..name1.count
        loop

         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('The name for' || name1(rec) || 'ways');
        end loop;
      code := code + 1;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: i tried this code......but it is now showing the 
"anonymous block completed" after executing the statement.

Comment: it is working now

Comment: serveroutput was off.....its working now...thanks a lot